# R remap xaxis when reshaping array

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

Consider the following example:

```
nt <- 5
a <- array(runif(10), dim=c(nt, 2))
t <- seq(0, 10, length.out=nt)
a <- data.frame(a)
```

where a is a timeseries with `5` observations and `2` features, and `t` consists of a vector of the time index at which each observation was taken. I want to plot the array `a` as a vector such that the x axis is the time index and the y axis is the original intensity in the array `a`.

I can do this with the following code:

```
  xlabel <- 'time'
  ylabel <- 'intensity'
  legend='feature'
  dsm = melt(a)
  colnames(dsm) <- c(xlabel, legend, ylabel)

  aplot <- ggplot(data=dsm, aes_string(x=xlabel, y=ylabel, group=legend, color=legend)) +
    geom_line(alpha=.2) +
    scale_y_continuous()
```

Which will plot the observations as `0, 1, ...` and not the elements of `t` as I hope, due to the fact that when I melt `a` it just collapses the original array such that the `x, y` indices are just the coordinates in the original matrix. Is there an elegant way to replace these coordinates, with a sort of remapping? Something that would, for say, allow me to very easily just do `{0:0, 1:t[1], 2:t[2], 3:t[3]...}` to the time column of `dsm`? I can see that I could manually do this in a for-loop, but that seems very unnecessary, and I am sure there is some built in that will do this for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not reproducible example code: `colnames(dsm) <- c(xlabel, legend, ylabel)` `Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]`

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(melt(data.table(a, time = t), "time"), aes(time, value, group = variable)) + geom_line()`

Comment: make it an answer ftw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(data.table(a, time = t), "time"), 
       aes(time, value, group = variable)) + 
    geom_line()
```